# Android code to set thumbnail to `VideoView`

Tags: android, android-videoview

I want to display thumbnail in `VideoView`. I tried the following solution but that is not working.

```
fun retriveVideoFrameFromVideo(videoId : String): Bitmap? {
        var bitmap: Bitmap? = null
        var mediaMetadataRetriever: MediaMetadataRetriever? = null
        try {
            mediaMetadataRetriever = MediaMetadataRetriever()
            mediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(AKAMAI_VIDEO_DOMAIN + videoId + AKAMAI_VIDEO_SUFFIX_URL, HashMap<String, String>())
            bitmap = mediaMetadataRetriever.getFrameAtTime(1, MediaMetadataRetriever.OPTION_CLOSEST)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            throw Throwable("Exception in retriveVideoFrameFromVideo(String videoPath)"
                    + e.message)
        } finally {
            if (mediaMetadataRetriever != null) {
                mediaMetadataRetriever.release()
            }
        }
        return bitmap
    }
```

And `VideoView` takes time to load video.

Any help about these issues will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use this to create a thumbnail for the video

```
val bitmap = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(picturePathURI, MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND);
```